# what is the error with xamarin live player (can't resolve name on Element ( Exception ) )

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to run my xamarin application on my lenovo tablet but i get this error

> Can't resolve name on Element (Exception)

Here is my XAML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App6.QuotesPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Next"></Button>
            <Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="50" Minimum="16"></Slider>
            <Label x:Name="lbl" FontSize="{Binding Source={Reference x:slider} , Path=Value}"></Label>            
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this error occurs because `Button x:Name` is missing. you need something like this :

```
 <Button x:Name="btn" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Next"></Button>
```

And change label font-size to :

```
"{Binding Source={x:Reference slider} , Path=Value}"
```

Comment: I tried it and it did not solve the problem , I still receive the same error message at the the Debug Logs

Comment: @OmarAboFoul change label font size to "{Binding Source={x:Reference slider} , Path=Value}"

Comment: Yes This solved my problem , Thanks so much but where was the error ?